# socket.setTcpNoDelay(true) is not working

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a problem in sending data packet using tcp socket. What my program does is pretty simple: Firstly, a client socket connects to a server socket. Then the server socket sends 5 "hello" back to the client and the client outputs the 5 "hello" to the console. Both the client and server run on my local computer and below is the full code:

**Server:**

```
public class Server {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(60009);
    serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
    System.out.println("Server started!");
    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    socket.getOutputStream().write("hello".getBytes());
    socket.getOutputStream().write("hello".getBytes());
    socket.getOutputStream().write("hello".getBytes());
    socket.getOutputStream().write("hello".getBytes());
    socket.getOutputStream().write("hello".getBytes());
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    is.read(new byte[100]);
}
```

}

**Client:**

```
public class Client {
static Socket socket;
static byte[] buffer;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 60009));
    buffer = new byte[100];

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = socket.getInputStream();
                    is.read(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                    String rcvStr = new String(buffer);
                    System.out.println(rcvStr);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Given the code posted above, my expected output should be like this:

hello

hello

hello

hello

hello

However, the actual result I get is this:

hello

hellohellohellohello

My problem is right here. The result output does not follow the order I send them on server. I ask the server to send 5 "hello" one by one. But according to the result, it seems like what the server really does is it sends one "hello" at first and then sends the rest of four "hello" all together.

After searching the google, I found many people relate this problem to the so called Nagle algorithm which will avoid tcp socket sending short data packet immediately for increasing the efficiency of network use. To disable the Nagle algorithm, you only need to call setTcpNoDelay(true) on socket. Then the computer will send whatever you ask it to send right away. But unfortunately, after I disabled the Nagle algorithm, my client still outputs the same result as above. Can you guys tell me what am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't use TCP as a messaging system, with or without the Nagle algorithm. It is a byte-stream protocol.

Comment: That's a good point. But I really want to know I I can send whatever data immediately and receive the same without let the os decide if it needs to buffer the output for me. I want it to work like the output and input function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing. But, this may disappoint you, the Nagle algorithm has nothing to do with what happens here.

When you run the client and the server, and you inspect the network traffic using `tcpdump`, you can see that each call to `write` generates one TCP packet with the string `hello`. This happens both when you do call `setTcpNoDelay(true)` and when you don't. In conclusion, the sender works pretty much as expected: you're writing to an unbuffered `OutputStream` and data gets immediately sent out.

[image: Traffic dump]

So the reason why you're reading four packets at once is because the packets get buffered up *on the receiving end*. I don't think there's much you can do about that. If you need to distinguish between successive messages in a TCP stream, you need to look at various [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I tried to monitor the tcp traffic as you did in wireshark but it failed because the OS i am using is windows which not able to capture the local loopback traffic. I guess it is not possible for the client socket to wait and buffer couple of packets to output. inputstream.read is supposed to read all the stuff in the receive buffer. Only the outputstream.write is kind of unpredictable. So i am wondering if the each tcp packet generates after the server called write is the packet containing "hello" or just any ack packet that test the connection establishment.

Comment: In the screenshot above, packets # 5, 6, 9, 11 and 13 are data packets containing "hello". So the sender actually is very predictable :-)

Comment: I found I made a mistake in my code. I should allocate a new buffer each time before the inputstream.read(buffer) to avoid the overlapping of data.After the change of my code, things get interesting. I still get the same result. But if I put the write("hello") in an indefinite loop in the server ,then I got a list of hello,each hello in a line. And, if I add a Thread.sleep(1000) in each loop, then I get a list of mix of "hello" or "hello hello hello".That's really weird. Hopefully I describe it clearly.Thanks for your help again!

Comment: What you need to do is keep track of how many bytes you have actually read. The call to `read()` returns you the count of bytes. You must use this value otherwise your code will not be correct. Nothing else is weird about what you're seeing :) It's just TCP working as designed.

Comment: OK. I will stick to that.Thanks:)

Comment: Oh,I forgot to accept your answer. Now its the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use buffered readers and writers, separate each message with a newLine and use a reader to read each line:

First, setup your streams:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
bufferedWriter.flush();
```

Then write messages at the server by calling a function like this:

```
private void rawSend(final String rawText) throws IOException {
    bufferedWriter.write(rawText);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.flush();
}
```

Then on the client, read lines like this:

```
final String rawPacket = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You COULD use sender side's socket.setTcpNoDelay(true) and available() on the receiving side:

```
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int bytesAvail = 0;
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = socket.getInputStream();
                while (bytesAvail == 0) {
                    bytesAvail = is.available();
                    if (bytesAvail == 0) Thread.sleep(40); // ugly - use async IO
                }
                bytesAvail = is.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvail);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                String rcvStr = new String(buffer, 0, bytesAvail);
                System.out.println(rcvStr);
        }
    }
```

... but Lord Moon's answer's design is more robust.